# How to protect a Web API using ASP.NET 5 MVC 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, restful-authentication, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a nice ASP.NET 5 / MVC 6 app up and running. Essentially for this purpose it is just the normal sample app you get when you start a new project to keep it simple. So far I can:

- Register a user
- Login
- Logout
- Protect a page (forcing login etc)

Now, what I would like is to provide an API mechanism for a app to login and get an authentication token. Specifically I am working on two mobile apps to test with, one using Angular / Cordova and one using Xamarin.

I have looked high and low and I cannot seem to find an example yet that shows how to make this work. Every example I find so far assumes the user will login via the normal web form / post cycle and then be taken to a page that loads Angular and this the authentication token is already in the browser.

The relevant code from the AccountController.cs file for the MVC controller is below. What I ultimately want is the equivalent functionality but from a pure API call that allows Angular / Xamarin to send it a username / password and get back a authentication token or failure.

```
    // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
            // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set shouldLockout: true
            var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            }
            if (result.IsLockedOut)
            {
                return View("Lockout");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

What is the recommended way to protect a Web API using ASP.NET MVC 6?

Comment: This could help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25928738/1295965

Comment: And this could help you http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/ it's not vnext, but I was able to migrate this approach to vnext.

Comment: You have to implement the API with "Individual Accounts". It's pretty straightforward. You Register using Username/Password & the Web API provides you with a token, which you use to get access to API.

Comment: I have a working app that I am working on, but I can't share that code to public as it's still work in progress and it's commercial project. This specific set code is needed by lot of developers, so I would be dedicating to write a full blog-post about this during this weekend, so extend the bounty by 1 more week.

Comment: @alekkowalczyk How did you manage to create a token? ASP.NET 5 doesn't come with a built in OAuth authorisation server.

Comment: I used this a while back as a reference https://github.com/wcabus/MvcOverWebApi

Comment: Have you tried ASP.NET Identity 2.0? There are many working examples for it for MVC5, and [you can migrate the code to MVC6](http://mvc.readthedocs.org/en/latest/migration/migratingauthmembership.html)

Comment: @KunalB. I am afraid it's not possible to extend the bounty.

Comment: Anyways I will make a blog post this weekend & put the link here.

Comment: @Martin - I have made the blogpost - http://blog.kbajpai.com/2015/08/bookstore-web-api-with-authorization.html

Answer (score 3):

I think the recommended approach for securing WebApi2 is through an Authorisation Server. The Authorisation Server takes care of generating tokens. But based on [this](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/83), the OAuth2 based authorization server that is part of Katana3 has been dropped from Asp.Net 5.

I assume your app is not a live app yet, since both ASP.NET 5 and MVC 6 are not in their final release stage yet. So if you are okay to change your identity/authentication process, you could use Thinktecture's [IdentityServer3](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/).

Dominick Baier has blogged about the [The State of Security on ASP.NET 5 and MVC 6](http://leastprivilege.com/2015/07/22/the-state-of-security-in-asp-net-5-and-mvc-6-oauth-2-0-openid-connect-and-identityserver/) and where IdSvr3 comes into the picture. That blog has a link to a Github repository for sample API Controller, and also a API client. It also has sample for an MVC Web app. [And it can work with Asp.Net Identity.](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.AspNetIdentity)

**UPDATE:**

If that does not work for you, you could try [AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server). Note that it has open issues on Github, so you may encounter problems using it. Note also its dependencies, particularly the *azureadwebstacknightly*.

Please note that ASP.NET 5 and MVC 6 may be in a stable beta release, but they are still in *beta* release. It could still change.

Also, IdSvr3 v2.0 may be in its final release, but it is developed by a separate team. And it is only been released 2 weeks ago, so IMHO like most software, you can encounter things that may likely missed their tests. Note the [ASP.NET Team](https://twitter.com/aspnet), last week, [tweeted](https://twitter.com/aspnet/status/634650921507549184) about IdSvr3's (v2.0) release, so it appears they are endorsing it.

Comment: Interesting. I am looking at their solution. The unfortunate part with IdentityServer3 is that they don't support Core CLR.

Comment: Not yet but they plan to. Dominick commented on this in a response he posted on that Asp.net OAuth2 issue log that I cited/linked to.

Comment: Just as FYI, the sample isn't working. I had to do multiple changes just to get it started.

Comment: @Martin, it might help others using the samples if you log the issue you encountered in the relevant Github repository issue track, if it's not already there.

Comment: I already logged a couple of issues (e.g. two Startup.Configure method, unable to resolve packages, etc.). The sample that they provide don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the blog-post that I had promised, this is the first draft, and would be helpful for someone who has a some experience with ASP.NET MVC 5: [Bookstore - Web API with Authorization](http://blog.kbajpai.com/2015/08/bookstore-web-api-with-authorization.html)

Complete Source at Github: https://github.com/kbajpai/bookstore

The API with Authorization:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Description;
using Bookstore.Models;

namespace Bookstore.Controllers
{
  public class BooksController : ApiController
  {
    private BooksDbContext db = new BooksDbContext();

    // GET: api/Books
    [Authorize(Roles="superuser,user")]
    public IQueryable<Book> GetBooks()
    {
      return db.Books;
    }

    // GET: api/Books/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(Book))]
    [Authorize(Roles = "superuser,user")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetBook(string id)
    {
      Book book = await db.Books.FindAsync(id);
      if (book == null)
      {
        return NotFound();
      }

      return Ok(book);
    }

    // PUT: api/Books/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
    [Authorize(Roles = "superuser")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PutBook(string id, Book book)
    {
      if (!ModelState.IsValid)
      {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
      }

      if (id != book.Id)
      {
        return BadRequest();
      }

      db.Entry(book).State = EntityState.Modified;

      try
      {
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
      }
      catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
      {
        if (!BookExists(id))
        {
          return NotFound();
        }
        else
        {
          throw;
        }
      }

      return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }

    // POST: api/Books
    [Authorize(Roles = "superuser")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(Book))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostBook(Book book)
    {
      if (!ModelState.IsValid)
      {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
      }

      db.Books.Add(book);

      try
      {
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
      }
      catch (DbUpdateException)
      {
        if (BookExists(book.Id))
        {
          return Conflict();
        }
        else
        {
          throw;
        }
      }

      return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = book.Id }, book);
    }

    // DELETE: api/Books/5
    [Authorize(Roles = "superuser")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(Book))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DeleteBook(string id)
    {
      Book book = await db.Books.FindAsync(id);
      if (book == null)
      {
        return NotFound();
      }

      db.Books.Remove(book);
      await db.SaveChangesAsync();

      return Ok(book);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
      if (disposing)
      {
        db.Dispose();
      }
      base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private bool BookExists(string id)
    {
      return db.Books.Count(e => e.Id == id) > 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The question was for ASP.NET 5 MVC 6, not ASP.NET MVC 5.

Comment: Is MVC6 very different from MVC5? The idea is same.

Comment: Yes Kunal, MVC6 is very different from MVC5

Comment: @KunalB. Incredibly so. With a whole new breakdown of the framework into components and its rebuilding for cross-platform.. this really is a rebirth of MVC and migration scenarios are from trivial in many ways.