# .net 5 MVC 6 web api using existing identityDb for authentication

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on having native app be able to authenticate to a web api which uses an existing identity db database created from MVC6.  I understand this is not a secure way of doing things as per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30989636/how-to-protect-a-web-api-using-asp-net-5-mvc-6).  However, until I can figure out how to get IdentityServer3 working with a database I thought I would try a simple web api that authenticates to a database I already created when I built a standard MVC 6 web app.  Here is what I did:

Created an asp.net 5 web api from the template and added the following:
Settings:
appsettings.json I added:

```
"Data": {
    "DefaultConnection": {
      "ConnectionString": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=aspnet5-TestUsers-eaf0c85f-23e4-4603-97ce-b9f49ee1d167;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
    }
  },
```

Startup:

```
services.AddEntityFramework()
                .AddSqlServer()
                .AddDbContext<ApiDbContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));
```

Models:

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser
    {
    }
```

DBContext:

```
public class ApiDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser>
    {
    }
```

Controller:

```
private readonly UserManager<AppUser> _userManager;
private readonly SignInManager<AppUser> _signInManager;
private readonly ILogger _logger;
...
public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> Post([FromBody]LoginModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid) { 
                string user = model.userid;
                string passwd = model.password;

                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.userid, model.password, false, lockoutOnFailure: false);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation(1, "User logged in.");
                    return new string[] { user };
                }
                else
                {
                    return new string[] { "Failed" };
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return new string[] { "Incorrect format received"};
            }
        }
```

However, it bombs at the _signInManager line with the error:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.

So apparently _signInManager is Null because I know the model is fine because I am printing the userid and password and they are there.

What am I missing so I can use the signInManager in a web api?

Answer (score 0):

I went back yet another time to see what was different between the web api and the web app, since the web app auth was working fine.  Here is what I added to get it working:

controller needed a constructor:

```
public AuthController(
            SignInManager<AppUser> signInManager,
            ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<AuthController>();
        }
```

Which got rid of my other error but produced the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: No authentication handler is
>   configured to handle the scheme: Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Application

So after researching that I needed to add to startup:
configureservices:

```
services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApiDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

configure:

```
app.UseIdentity();
```

Adding these to the above allowed me to post JSON with userid and password.